# search in fread definition to find string

Tags: php, arrays, fread

I have this:

```
$JunkHead3 = @fread($fp,180);
```

Echo "$JunkHead3", print this:

```
al-Arena @ DeathMatchde_dust2cstrikeDust2 Only/dwÿÿÿÿDstoqn”;Bhtrl**7 !DEmesyhGBLo6ata7#CN3D0S3GA3M!73 | NestL3 L!oNà‘÷D{V
```

I need to search for `/d` and add +1 to print in this case `"w"`

How to do that ?
I try with array_search:

```
print(array_search('/d', $JunkHead3)+1);
```

but without success...

Answer (score 0):

The `array_search()` function is for arrays, what you have is a string.

You can use `strpos()` to determine the position and `substr()` to extract the portion you need.

```
$index = strpos($JunkHead3, '/d');
$result = substr($JunkHead3, $index+2, 1);
```

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

However I prefer using regular expressions, even though at first they seem a bit cryptic.

```
$result = preg_replace('/^.*\\/d(.).*$/', '$1', $JunkHead3);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php